# jQuery - Add Remove Class - Set Value Of Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I need this to Add Remove Classes & Set Value of nextAll input.

I can make it work but it only works for one time. I need it to be more like a toogle.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fa-circle").click(function () {
        $(this).nextAll('input').first().val('Yes');
        $(this).removeClass("fa-circle light_gray").addClass("fa-check green");
    });
    $(".fa-check").click(function () {
        $(this).nextAll('input').first().val('No');
        $(this).removeClass("fa-check green").addClass("fa-circle light_gray");
    });
});
```

```css
.green {
    color: #8FCE35;
}

.light_gray {
    color: #DDDDDD;
}

.point {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="candi_elections_table" align="center" style="text-align: left;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>198</td>
            <td>
                <span class="fa-check font16 green point">CLICK HERE</span>
                <input id="198" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="198" vk_11844="subscribed">
            </td>
            <td>Something 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>
                <span class="fa-circle font16 light_gray point">CLICK HERE</span>
                <input id="200" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="200" vk_11844="subscribed">
            </td>
            <td>Something 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>201</td>
            <td>
                <span class="fa-check font16 green point">CLICK HERE</span>
                <input id="201" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="201" vk_11844="subscribed">
            </td>
            <td>Something 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>202</td>
            <td>
                <span class="fa-circle font16 light_gray point">CLICK HERE</span>
                <input id="202" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="202" vk_11844="subscribed">
            </td>
            <td>Something 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyone can see what i am doing wrong?

- the fa-check & fa-circle are awesome fonts

I also got it in jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9bonuyyn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added class. And also you can shorten your `js` like following.

```
$('.candi_elections_table').on("click", ".fa-circle, .fa-check", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-circle')) {
        $(this).nextAll('input').first().val('Yes');
    } else {
        $(this).nextAll('input').first().val('No');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-check green fa-circle light_gray");
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9bonuyyn/5/)**

Comment: It needs a $(document).ready(function() { } to wok in my page

Comment: Yes if you add your `js` before `.candi_elections_table` the `$(document).ready(function() { })` is needed. @John

Answer (score 1):

`$(SELECTOR)` will select only those element which are present in the `DOM` and which matches the `selector`.

As class of the element is being updated dynamically, use [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Basically we are attaching event on parent which is persistent throughout the life-cycle of the application and by specifying the `target-element` which are children of the parent mentioned.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.candi_elections_table').on('click', ".fa-circle", function() {
    $(this).nextAll('input').first().val('Yes');
    $(this).removeClass("fa-circle light_gray").addClass("fa-check green");
  });


  $('.candi_elections_table').on('click', ".fa-check", function() {
    $(this).nextAll('input').first().val('No');
    $(this).removeClass("fa-check green").addClass("fa-circle light_gray");
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: #8FCE35;
}
.light_gray {
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
.point {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="candi_elections_table" align="center" style="text-align: left;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>198</td>
      <td>
        <span class="fa-check font16 green point">CLICK HERE</span>
        <input id="198" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="198" vk_11844="subscribed">
      </td>
      <td>Something 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>
        <span class="fa-circle font16 light_gray point">CLICK HERE</span>
        <input id="200" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="200" vk_11844="subscribed">
      </td>
      <td>Something 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>201</td>
      <td>
        <span class="fa-check font16 green point">CLICK HERE</span>
        <input id="201" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="201" vk_11844="subscribed">
      </td>
      <td>Something 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>202</td>
      <td>
        <span class="fa-circle font16 light_gray point">CLICK HERE</span>
        <input id="202" class="" type="text" data-tooltip="" data-load-state="" data-inputmask="" style="" title="" placeholder="" value="" name="202" vk_11844="subscribed">
      </td>
      <td>Something 4</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9bonuyyn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It only works once because you add the event listener when `$(document).ready`, at that time only the first and the third has class `fa-circle`, so these two element will not run `fa-check` click event, even after click - you add `fa-check` class to them. The same for second and fourth.

Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-circle, .fa-check").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).hasClass('fa-circle') ? 'Yes':'No';
    $(this).nextAll('input').first().val(text);
    $(this).toggleClass( "fa-circle light_gray fa-check green" )
  });
});
```

Hope this is useful.